# Are there any settings with rules for neural interfaces?

Tags: laws, laws-of-robotics, mind-control

Can't find a single book which puts together a universal set of rules for neural interfaces to protect people (like the three laws of robotics). Are there any that exist?

Comment: This site is dedicated to answering questions about published science fiction or fantasy works. We could answer the first bit of your question, about existing works, but this isn't a good venue to ask for critiques of your own work in progress.

Comment: Agreed, I don't want critique for what I wrote. Your edit is better than my original.

Comment: Protect people from what, exactly? Greg Egan's "TAP" concerns the danger of being fed a mental state like <<suicidal gloom>> or <<heart-stopping terror>>. Greg Bear's *Eternity* describes a safety protocol for mental contact with a hostile alien.

Comment: Post-edit this has just become a "list of works" question.

Comment: @Beta - what does [Perl testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol) have to do with SciFi?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Or, at least, 'not in the popular published canon.'

There are a few here and there that posit rules against it wholesale, or differ on if a nerological clone of someone is a person / is the same person / is just a program, but no well-intentioned discussion of the rules thereof.

Comment: Something perhaps like: The Cognitive Manipulation Rulings
1. CM shall never interfere with an active cognitive process (thought control).
2. CM shall be completely under the control of the individual. (Such as cant send/receive confidential information) 
3. CM may be used without consent on an individual only if the individual seeks to use CM on another without their consent

Comment: I think this answer might be a good one if you presented examples from books that were the "few here and there". Otherwise, this isn't much of an answer saying "Nope, doesn't exist"

Comment: Agreed, but specific examples fail to arise.  it's annoyingly hard to prove a negative.